# Permission denied editing .bash_profile rbenv init on mac

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, rbenv

Hung up on editing the .bash_profile while running rbenv init on mac.

```
$ rbenv init
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

but get the message:
-bash: /Users/macbookpro/.bash_profile: Permission denied

[image: .bash_profile: Permission denied]

I try to edit the .bash_profile directly but get the message:

[image: You don't own the file ".bash_profile"]

I found this command to see the users:

```
$ ls -la ~ | grep bash
```

It shows:

```
-rw------- 1 macbookpro .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       .bash_profile
```

If I open the file using command:

```
$ sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

I guess I need to add this to .bash_profile:

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Or is it just the inner "part" of this?
Also how do I save this or do we have any easier solution (pretending my name is Fname-Lname)?

Comment: Can I bring this back to my ownership or shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `sudo` in order to edit/append `~/.bash_profile` on `macOS`.

```
sudo echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Or just as you had done at the end of your question.

Comment: I still get the same message when using sudo: 
-bash: /Users/macbookpro/.bash_profile: Permission denied

Comment: You could try changing the ownership to your user: `chown $(id -u -n) ~/.bash_profile`, or if that won't work try:`sudo chown $(id -u -n) ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Your very last comment helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue what i did was i gave .bash_profile writable permission.

```
cd ~
sudo chmod 0777 .bash_profile
nano .bash_profile
```

After adding your modifcations you can now save the file with `^O` and enter (return) after that you use `^x` to exit.

**Note:** ^ is the control button